# Read in an XML Block

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I am developing a webservice - I have cretaed a TestWebserive to pass across the data I want.  Basically it will read in an XML file, use an XSL to transform it and then pass it on.

So the XML I am reading in is as follows:

```
                                <utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                    <utcc:AttributeName>Value1</utcc:AttributeName>
                                    <utcc:AttributeValue>1</utcc:AttributeValue>
                                </utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                <utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                    <utcc:AttributeName>Value2</utcc:AttributeName>
                                    <utcc:AttributeValue>2</utcc:AttributeValue>
                                </utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                <utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                    <utcc:AttributeName>Value3</utcc:AttributeName>
                                    <utcc:AttributeValue>3</utcc:AttributeValue>
                                </utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                <utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                    <utcc:AttributeName>Value4</utcc:AttributeName>
                                    <utcc:AttributeValue>4</utcc:AttributeValue>
                                </utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                <utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                    <utcc:AttributeName>Value5</utcc:AttributeName>
                                    <utcc:AttributeValue>5</utcc:AttributeValue>
                                </utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                <utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                    <utcc:AttributeName>Value6</utcc:AttributeName>
                                    <utcc:AttributeValue>6</utcc:AttributeValue>
                                </utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                <utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                    <utcc:AttributeName>Value7</utcc:AttributeName>
                                    <utcc:AttributeValue>7</utcc:AttributeValue>
                                </utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                <utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                    <utcc:AttributeName>Value8</utcc:AttributeName>
                                    <utcc:AttributeValue>8</utcc:AttributeValue>
                                </utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                <utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
                                    <utcc:AttributeName>Value9</utcc:AttributeName>
                                    <utcc:AttributeValue>9</utcc:AttributeValue>
                                </utcc:OrderItemAttribute>
```

So I then have an OrderInput class and within it the following code:

```
private OrderItemAttribute[] orderItemAttribute;

[XmlElement("OrderItemAttribute")]
        public OrderItemAttribute[] OrderItemAttribute
        {
            get { return orderItemAttribute; }
            set { orderItemAttribute = value; }
        }
```

and then another class - OrderItemAttribute which has the following:

```
    private string attributeName;
    private string attributeValue;

    [XmlElement("AttributeName")]
    public string AttributeName
    {
        get { return attributeName; }
        set { attributeName = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement("AttributeValue")]
    public string AttributeValue
    {
        get { return attributeValue; }
        set { attributeValue = value; }
    }
```

Now within my Test Webservice I have the following to pass in test values:

```
 orderInput.OrderItemAttribute[0].AttributeName = "Value1TestName";
 orderInput.OrderItemAttribute[0].AttributeValue = "Value1TestValue";
```

I am wondering instead of doing this for all [1] [2], etc is there a way I can do a foreach loop on this and read in all the values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase `OrderItemAttribute` is a array if think you should be able to something like this:

```
foreach(var order in orderInput.OrderItemAttribute)
    {
        order.AttributeName="Value1TestName";
        order.AttributeValue="Value1TestValue";
    }
```

Comment: there was a reason I designed OrderItemAttribute as an array yesterday and then had some brain freeze this morning trying to work out a better way to read it than [0], [1], etc :)

Comment: I almost did not answer it because it was to easy :P .. Still everyone have brain freezes the next time probably me :)